# Is there a way to group AWS data pipeline on Console to be put them under a folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

We have been migrating our relation data base data to Redshift using AWS data pipeline. As with time number of data pipeline has increases to a point where it is difficult to easily find one. Also we have data data pipeline for EMR activity for Spark so it is really getting confusing.

Is there a way we can create folders for AWS data pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to create folders within the UI. I'd recommend using a naming convention and using the search feature.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing.